# Webpack module federation micro frontend

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, export, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to make a micro frontend but I doing something wrong and I dont know what. I am exposing a few things from my Main frontend and a few things from my subfront end but I only got one of them to work while the others dont.
This is the ModuleFederationPlugin from my main frontend:

```
    {
        name: "MainFrontend",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            "./constants": "./src/constants",
            "./appState": "./src/store/index",
            "./generalActions": "./src/store/slices/general",
            "./ErrorModal": "./src/components/ErrorModal",
        },
        remotes: {
            ManageUsers: "ManageUsers@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
        },
        shared: {
            ...deps,
            react: {
                singleton: true,
                requiredVersion: deps.react,
            },
            "react-dom": {
                singleton: true,
                requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
            },
        },
    }
```

This is the ModuleFederationPlugin from the sub frontend:

```
    {
        name: "ManageUsers",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            "./UserDetails": "./src/App",
            "./manageUserState": "./src/store/manageUser",
        },
        remotes: {
            MainFrontend:
                "MainFrontend@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js",
        },
        shared: {
            ...deps,
            react: {
                singleton: true,
                requiredVersion: deps.react,
            },
            "react-dom": {
                singleton: true,
                requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
            },
        },
    }
```

Only the "./UserDetails" works correctly in the Main frontend but the rest just doesnt.
Here is how I am importing them:
In sub frontend:

```
import ErrorModal from "MainFrontend/ErrorModal";
import generalActions from "MainFrontend/generalActions";
```

In the Main frontend:

```
import manageUserState from "ManageUsers/manageUserState";
const UserDetails = React.lazy(() => import("ManageUsers/UserDetails")
```

Before anyone says to use React.lazy for all the other imports aswell, not everything I expose in the main frontend are react components. I also have already tried that with the ErrorModal in the sub frontend (because that one is a component) and that didnt work either.

Webpack just throws an Error that it can find the module because its looking for the ErrorModal in the path of the subfront end and not the main frontend. It also says something about a "Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration" if that somehow helps.
When I look into the network tab of the sub frontend I do see the four exposes from the Main frontend being requested successfully.